# Test API environment for development and testing

Tags: uber-api

Is there a test environment that we can uae to make "pretend calls" directly from our server to a RESTful api for development ?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow***

Answer (score 0):

Uber API has a sandbox: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/sandbox

"The Uber API Sandbox provides development endpoints for testing the functionality of an application without making calls to the production Uber platform. All requests made to the Sandbox environment will be ephemeral."

Comment: Can you accept my answer if this is what you were looking for? Thanks!